# How to fix "Stream has already been operated upon or closed” error with nested map functions

Tags: java, java-stream

I came across "Stream has already been operated upon or closed" when trying to exec Functions on two streams and produce one out come.

I already tried using StreamSupplier, but seems it does not solve the problem, it does get solved if I convert both streams to list of strings and do nested loop. But I want to see what will be the stream solution for this.

The current code I have is

```java
String[] str1 = new String[]{"A","B","C"};
String[] str2 = new String[]{"a","b","c"};
private Stream<String> method(final Stream<String> str1,
            final Stream<String> str2) {
       return str1
               .flatMap(s1 -> str2
                       .map(s2 -> simpleStringConcatFunction_1(s1) + simpleStringConcatFunction_2(s2));
```

Let's say s1 is a 3 elements string list, also s2. The output shall be a 9 elements.
like

Aa,
Ab,
Ac,
Ba,
Bb,
Bc,
Ca,
Cb,
Cc

I used double loop which achieved these the code is

```java
private Stream<String> generateFilePatterns(final Stream<String> str1,
            final Stream<String> str2) {
        List<String> list1 = str1.collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> list2 = str2.collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for( String s1 : list1){
            for(String s2 : list2){
                list.add(simpleStringConcatFunction_1(s1) + simpleStringConcatFunction_2(s2);
            }
        }
        return list.stream();
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "I already tried using StreamSupplier."  The actual solution is that you can't just use `str2`, but you must pass in something that can create *fresh* streams for `str2`.  Not really any way around that.

Answer (score 1):

Do half of what you did in non-stream code, i.e. take a snapshot of `str2`, so you can stream it multiple times:

```
List<String> list2 = str2.collect(Collectors.toList());
return str1.flatMap(s1 -> list2.stream()
                               .map(s2 -> simpleStringConcatFunction_1(s1) +
                                          simpleStringConcatFunction_2(s2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the output using 2 streams and a `flatMap` to combine the pratial results

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] str1 = new String[]{"A","B","C"};
    String[] str2 = new String[]{"a","b","c"};

    // The internal for
    Function<String, Stream<String>> combinationStream = str1Element -> Arrays.stream(str2)
            .map(str2Element -> str1Element.toUpperCase() + str2Element.toLowerCase());

    // The external for
    List<String> result = Arrays.stream(str1)
            .flatMap(combinationStream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

**Output**

> [Aa, Ab, Ac, Ba, Bb, Bc, Ca, Cb, Cc]